# CSS not working in CodePen

Tags: html, css

This is a simple question and I'm sure someone will have the answer quickly within looking at it, but my css is not working and I'm not sure what I've done wrong! Any help appreciated!

The code is below, but the link to the codepen is http://codepen.io/benyaaalex/pen/BRBMeW?editors=1000

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .container-fluid {
      margin: 5%;
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what is not working? if you're referring to the `container-fluid` not having background color, that's because there is no content inside it.

Comment: there is no content inside what you are styling. If you add text into the `container-fluid` `div`, you will get a result

Comment: Oh ok, learning moment :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is no content inside the div you are trying to style, if you add some text and re-run you'll see that it works.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine. But you're not going to get any background color, margin, etc. for your div until it actually has some content in it. An empty div has no visible properties in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

> my css is not working and I'm not sure what I've done wrong!

your `CSS` is not the issue.

- there is no content inside the `div` tag hence you won't be able to see any change.
- Also, you'll need the `html` tags.

---

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <style>
        body {
          background-color: blue;
        }
        .container-fluid {
          margin: 5%;
          background-color: red;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```